# Which jQuery plugins used in k2.pl?

Tags: jquery, hover, drag

I'm looking for the right jQuery plugin used to do the draggable slider in the home page on this website http://www.k2.pl/#!/en/main/ ?

I've just tried to do this with this http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/ but it isn't really a success...

Thank you in advance for all your ideas !

Alexis

Comment: I guess you should ask this question here: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can start from here:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="/static/front/js/libs/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>

<script src="/static/front/js/libs/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script src="/static/front/js/libs/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js"></script>
<script src="/static/front/js/libs/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
<script src="/static/front/js/libs/swfobject.js"></script>
<script src="/static/front/js/libs/sammy-0.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/static/front/js/plugins.js"></script>
<script src="/static/front/js/script.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer... But how difficult is to understand how did the developer in a compressed js file (like script.min.js). Do you know what I mean ?